# How to sort alphabet first and then numeric in unix

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I have a file containing 1 column:

```
1
2
a
b
0
```

The expected outcome:

```
a
b
0
1
2
```

If I use sort alone, the outcome would become 1->2->a->b which is not I want.
Is there any way I can sort alphabet first and then numeric? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -g <inputfile
a
b
0
1
2
```

Additional example:

```
cat inputfile
1
0
2
3
sd
35
76
23
asd


sort -g inputfile
asd
sd
0
1
2
3
23
35
76
```

Comment: Grateful if you could answer my another question similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483463/how-to-sort-alphanumeric-column-in-unix-with-alphabet-first-and-then-numeric