# How to sort alphanumeric column in unix with alphabet first and then numeric

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

Suppose I have a text file:

```
08174 C6517298
08184 P0785411
08184 K0255564
01234 56789012
09098 A9877756
```

I would like to sort the second column with alphabet first and then numeric

The expected outcome should be:

```
09098 A9877756
08174 C6517298
08184 K0255564
08184 P0785411
01234 56789012
```

I tried `sort -gk2,2` and `sort -k2,2`, both do not give me the correct result. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `-gk2,2` with `-k2g` (you meant the `-k` option, right?) , then add `-k2`

```
sort -k2g -k2 file
```

The key definition syntax is `F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]`, where `F` is the field number (`2`, in particular); `OPTS` is one or more single-letter ordering options `[bdfgiMhnRrV]`.

Note, you don't need the `,2`, as it means to stop sorting at the second column, and the second column is the last.

The key option priorities are applied in the order you passed them in the command, i.e. `-k2g` is applied first, then `-k2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $2,$0}' inputfile |sort -g |awk '{print $2,$3}'
09098 A9877756
08174 C6517298
08184 K0255564
08184 P0785411
01234 56789012
```

Comment: Could you please explain why sort -g alone doesnt work in this case? Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure, I hope some big gun will answer this. However, here in this answer , I tweaked the input to make it comprehensible to `sort -g`. Here , I moved the second column to the start of the line followed by sorting followed by removal of extra second column from the start of the line to bring it to original shape.